# yiiGridView - get currentpage by js

Tags: gridview, yii, pagination, dataprovider

i need to stick with the current page after update the yiigridview ($.fn.yiiGridView.update()), so my problem is how to get the current page in js:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
'id' => 'stocktake-details-grid',
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
      array(
        'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
        'name' => 'physical_qoh',
        'editable' => array(
            'url'       => array('StocktakeDetails/update'),
            'placement' => 'top',
            'onSave' => 'js: function(e, params) {
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update("stocktake-details-grid", {
                    data: {StocktakeDetails_page: currentpage}
                });
            }',
        ),
      ), 
)
```

Comment: by the way here is the alternative solution:
data: {StocktakeDetails_page: $("li.active").children().html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a $_GET attribute with a name something like [model_name]_page.

You can use the Network tab in Chrome Browser (i'm sure there is an equivalent in other browsers) to see what AJAX requests are being sent to check this.